# Possible methods of accessing L1 cache and specifying threads/cores

Tags: c, multithreading, caching, visual-basic, multi-core

**A faster prime number generator with hyperthreading and L1 cache**

About five years ago I wrote a simple VB widget to generate the first one million prime numbers and then port them to into its single VB listBox. It took about four hours on a 1.4 GHz Athlon with 1GB of PC-3200 DDR. I was wondering about some possible tips and tricks to greatly speed up this process with low-level hardware optimization and memory management in C.

Later it occurred to me that all prime numbers over ten end in either 1, 3, 7, or 9 so why not set up an algorithm to run in each core of a quad-core processor, and if possible, specify that the algorithm run inside the L1 cache.

What if we go up to 100,000,000 so each branch of this app will evaluate 10,000,000 prime candidates and return about 1,000,000 results

```
 ser[1]=new Array(1000000);
 ser[3]=new Array(1000000);
 ser[7]=new Array(1000000);   
 ser[9]=new Array(1000000);

 void run_array_loader(seed)
 {
     for(n=seed+10;n<100000000;n+=10)
     {
         for(x=3;x<sqrt(n);x+=2)
         {
             n%x==0?break;:continue;
         }
         ser[seed][]=n;
     }
 }
 run_array_loader(1); //in core[0]       
 run_array_loader(3); //in core[1]       
 run_array_loader(7); //in core[2]     
 run_array_loader(9); //in core[3]
```

What methods would we use to speed this up and to specify core allocation and cache utilization?

**Oct 20: Here is a breakdown of the results in C++**

[image]

**Summary**
 33:46 to perform 31.209 billion calculations, identifying 5,762,681 primes

Comment: 4 hours does seem slow. I just whipped up this in Ruby: `require 'prime'; Prime.each.take(1_000_000)` and it takes about 1/3 of a second on a Fall 2011 MacBook Pro on a single core, i.e. about 40000 times faster than your solution.

Comment: For "only" 1 million prime numbers, you don't need any fancy cache-aware parallel algorithms. Just the plain 3000 year old Sieve Of Eratosthenes you were taught in school should be plenty enough. Heck, even Trial Division shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: Well, you are calculating sqrt (n) at each iteration of the loop... And I'm curious whether 121 is a prime with your code or not. Anyway, since you have an expensive loop that doesn't access any memory, L1 cache or any other cache is quite irrelevant.

Comment: Holy micro optimization, Batman! You're falling into the old trap of getting tunnel vision about specific, shiny, low level optimizations. You're focusing on irrelevant aspects (as pointed out above, memory is not the bottleneck of this algorithm) while ignoring more promising optimization opportunities (the repeated `sqrt` call, the ListBox insertion) as well as different algorithms that could be orders of magnitude faster. I don't say this to bring you down as a person, you just lost sight of what's really important for optimization. Take several steps back and re-evaluated the big picture.

Comment: `sqrt` is called once per iteration of the inner loop (ignoring compiler optimizations). Nobody ever talked about using `n/2` as upper limit. The performance numbers are meaningless without comparison --- which is very difficult, especially with different hardware, but by Jörg W Mittag's numbers above, your current solution is far from the most efficient. This is **not** because you didn't micro optimize enough, but because the algorithm is fundamentally inefficient. Pull your head out of the sand. If you want to produce fast code, the "methodology" you pursue is useless.

Comment: I fail to understand what exactly you want to do with hyperthreading on this scenario. Actually, I'm pretty sure you are missing the point of hyperthreading entirely.

Comment: Also, as a rule of thumb - unless you are going for super specific  NASA-Level software or designing new hardware (or drivers for it), thinking about what register are you going to use for something is more often than not signal you are doing something wrong. Most machines are so powerful today that you don't really need to care what the cores are doing anymore for standard coding needs.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with such big numbers, choosing a faster algorithm will provide you with faster results independent of any low-level optimization.

Your loop incurs 100,000,000 / 10 * sqrt(100,000,000) / 2 = 50,000,000,000 operations / thread.

In contrast, by using [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) you would only require 100,000,000 * log(log(100,000,000)) ~~ 400,000,000 operations. That's 125 times faster on one thread than your implementation on 4 threads.

As you also mentioned a VB listbox, please also be aware that adding a large number of values to it can be quite slow.

**Later edit**: An update after you posted a benchmark.

Summing up the number of primes your code discovered yields 5,762,693. [This site](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html) however lists 5,761,455 primes under 100,000,000. So your code considered 1,238 numbers are prime when they are not.

Here is an example code using a different algorithm:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <int UpTo, typename OutputIt>
void populate_prime_numbers(OutputIt output)
{
    //stores 0 if the number is still considered a prime or 1 if certainly not
    auto valuesPtr = std::make_unique<std::bitset<UpTo>>();
    auto& values = *valuesPtr;
    for (int64_t divider = 3; ; divider += 2)
    {
        auto dividerSquare = divider * divider;
        if (dividerSquare >= UpTo) break;

        if (values[divider])
        {
            continue;
        }
        auto multiple = dividerSquare;
        while (multiple < UpTo)
        {
            values[multiple] = 1;
            multiple += divider;
        }
    }

    *output = 2;
    ++*output;

    for (int i = 3; i < UpTo; i += 2)
    {
        if (0 == values[i])
        {
            *output = i;
            ++*output;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> results;

    populate_prime_numbers<100000000>(back_inserter(results));

    std::cout << results.size() << " prime numbers < 100,000,000";
}
```

It outputs `5761455 prime numbers < 100,000,000` in only 1 second under x64. Single threaded code, no low-level optimizations.

Comment: Assuming the code is valid, we "break" out of the for(x) loop as soon as ***n*** is deemed to be non-prime. That quickly eliminates multiples of 3, 7, 11,13,17, etc.

Comment: @BrettBergan, you still divide every single prime by 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 and so on and so on. And every single number that has only large factors. Here's a hint: I have code that checks about 200 million numbers per second for primality using a sieve, on a five your old MacBook. Single threaded. _That's_ what you are aiming for.

Comment: D Jurcau: I would have voted you up for your close estimate of the number of calcs required, but this is my first post in this forum, and do not yet have voting clout. Nice call, though.

Answer (score 1):

Caching only becomes important once you have a decent implementation of a sieve. "Decent" meaning that it uses minimal memory, no unnecessary work, and efficient implementation. (I'd expect you for example not to store even numbers at all, and not to remove multiples of 3, 5, 7, 11 from the sieve but to not have them in the sieve in the first place when the sieve is initialised).

To optimise use of L1 cache, you don't just sieve one large array, but you perform the whole sieving operation on small chunks of data that fit into L1 cache, that is remove multiples of 13, 17, 19 etc. in one L1-cached size chunk of data, then remove them in the next chunk, and so on. No hardware tricks needed.

Comment: I agree. One schema i'd considered was starting two separate array threads. #1 starts at 5 and increments by 6, #2 starts at 7 and increments by 6. But the process that seemed better to me was to start eight threads at 11, 31, 23, 43, 17, 37, 19, and 29 incrementing each by 30. To my way of thinking, this would be ideal for an octo-core CPU or a hyperthreaded quad-core like the i7-6700.